# WooCommerce My Account page custom menu item with custom link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was able to create a new menu item "**Special Page**" using this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items' , 'kc_menu_panel_nav' );

function kc_menu_panel_nav() {
    $items = array(
        'dashboard'       => __( 'Dashboard', 'woocommerce' ),
        'orders'          => __( 'Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
        'downloads'       => __( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ),
        'edit-address'    => __( 'Addresses', 'woocommerce' ),
        'payment-methods' => __( 'Payment Methods', 'woocommerce' ),
        'edit-account'    => __( 'Account Details', 'woocommerce' ),
        'special-page' => __( 'Special Page', 'woocommerce' ), // My custom tab here
        'customer-logout' => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
    );

    return $items;
}
```

It redirects to my-account/special-page .How do I create a custom link for the special page link ?

Comment: Have a look to this: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/wiki/2.6-Tabbed-My-Account-page

Comment: You can check it to do it: https://gist.github.com/duroe5698/e89aa6c18b3e02e7a050e36eeed02664

Comment: This is also usefull: https://gist.github.com/claudiosanches/a79f4e3992ae96cb821d3b357834a005#file-custom-my-account-endpoint-php

Answer (score 0):

Here your page slug name is required.

your code

```
'special-page' =>
```

it's your page slug name For example like

```
'about-us' => __( 'My Page', 'woocommerce' ), // My custom tab here
```